# Структура база данных для магазина (закупки, склад и продажи)

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Небольшому магазину нужна база данных для обработки поступлений товаров (закупки), просмотру склада (остатки), оформлению заказов (продажи) и построению отчетов о продажах. Больше ничего не требуется, поэтому 1С не предлагать ))) хотя было бы интересно узнать как у них устроена БД для этой задачи.

Вроде бы задача простая, но... Я в этой области не силен, поэтому прошу помощи. Может кто знает, как это реализовано в 1С.

Все очень схематично, без углубления в название полей и т.п. Главное понять суть, как это может (должно) работать. Итак, я вижу следующую схему:

1. Таблица поступления товаров. Данные: название товара, закупочная цена, количество, и т.д.
2. Таблица склад. Данные в ней формируются из таблицы поступления товаров, так как нас интересует только реальное наличие на складе. Можно было получить эти данные из таблицы поступления напрямую, но в таблице поступления товаров, записей гораздо больше, чем реально товаров в наличии, ведь товар продается.
3. Таблица заказов (продажи). Данные: название проданного товара, продажная цена, количество, и т.д.
4. Связующая таблица. В ней отображаются связи между данными продаж и данными поступлений. Например: id продажи, количество, id поступления. Зачем эта таблица? Например, в одном заказе мы продали 3 шт товара, который получили по 1 шт в трех разных поставках по разной закупочной цене. Поэтому 1 записи продажи будет соответствовать 3 связующие записи.

Как должно работать: Заполняем поступление товарными позициями и приходуем товар. Количество оприходованного товара записывается в таблицу склад. Затем мы оформляем заказ. Количество проданного товара списывается со склада и записывается в связующую таблицу (сколько продано и из какой закупки).

Имея все эти данные мы можем сформировать отчеты:

- Отчет о наличии товаров на складе (таблица склад)
- Отчет о продажах (сколько продано товаров, цена продажи, цена закупки, прибыль)
- Отчет по партиям. Сколько из какой закупки продано, по какой цене и т.д.

Что смущает: Смущает вся эта конструкция ))) Может быть можно сделать проще (понятней) ?

Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: без знания предметной области, как у вас, ничего хорошего не выйдет. купите лучше 1с. вряд ли ваши попытки будут стоить дешевле 4600 рублей.

Comment: А как насчет помочь разобраться в вопросе? Пусть мои попытки будут стоить дороже, но я приобрету знания. Это не проект за деньги - это способ получить больше информации по теме. Надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: Найдите постановщика задачи, методиста по учету. Составьте вместе с ним ТЗ, погрУзитесь в область, сами переделаете ваши конструкции. Чтобы понять как учет реализован в 1С нужно таки смотреть 1С (документацию, курсы, саму конфигурацию...). В рамках ответа на такой вопрос рассказать систему учета не представляется возможным. В предыдущем вашем вопросе я частично указал на ошибки конструкции и правильное направление, в котором следует двигаться. Похоже не пригодилось.